# Is it possible to use node.js to communicate with queues/topics in Websphere MQ

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to Websphere MQ from my node.js clients.
I found two options

1.Using MQTT protocol
      --- we dont have license for MQTT 
2.Using MQLight
      -- We are using a older version of websphere MQ which does not have bridge between MQLight and MQ.

Are there any other options or is it possible to send messages from MQlight to MQ 7 queue/topic.

Answer (score 3):

There is no interoperability at any released version of MQ which supports AMQP, the protocol MQLight uses (at time of writing 8.0.0.3 is the newest version).

The MQTT protocol is supported from MQ 7.1+, and would allow a node.js MQTT client to create and consume messages to MQ via the MQ telemetry component.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open beta of MQ Light connectivity to MQ in MQ 8.0.0.3 as described here.  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/update_to_mq_s_beta_support_for_mq_light?lang=en

It is not supported formally because it is a beta. The beta is an early delivery of the MQ Light capability in MQ that we made a "statement of direction" about in the announce of MQ Version 8.

One  way to have this interwork with MQ V7 would be to configure a MQ V8.0.0.3 queue manager to interoperate with your existing MQ V7 queue manager, perhaps by including it in a cluster.